# Is there a workaround to this cleveref/thmtools bug: they think, multiple references is sequential

Tags: cleveref, thmtools

I have  a  [latex file](http://thales.csi.hu/mw/cref_bug.tex) that exhibits a cleveref/thmtools bug. In short: I have

```
\cref{problem:5,problem:4,problem:2}
```

in the file, and I expected to have, in the output

```
problems 2.1, 2.2, and 1.3.
```

Instead, I get

```
problems  2.1 to 1.3
```

In other words, `cleveref` thinks the list of references is an uninterrupted range.

Is there a fix to this or at least a workaround?  I'm using some features of `thmtools`, so I can't have `amsthm` alone.

A few remarks:

1. if I comment out the `\usepackage{thmtools}` line, then I get an
   acceptable output

   problems 1.3, 2.1, and 2.2

so it's the interplay between `thmtools` and `cleveref` that messes things up.

2. Using the `declaretheorem` commands don't make a difference.
3. I have a [diff of the aux files](http://thales.csi.hu/mw/cref_bug.aux.diff): one with `thmtools` loaded,
   and the other without `thmtools`.
4. I am running `pdfTeX`, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live
   2014)
5. The sample file I am giving is pretty much minimal: it's
   important for the bug that the numbering of the problem and `defn`
   environments are by section, and that the two environments share a
   counter.

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround consists of writing the cross-referencing instruction as

```
\cref{problem:5,problem:4,,problem:2}
```

Note the double comma between `problem:4` and `problem:2`. This will give you

> Hint: just use problems 2.1, 2.2 and 1.3.

*Addendum*: If you want a comma in the output after "2.2" and before "and", you'll also need to provide the instruction

```
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and~}
```

(The default setting is *not* to insert the comma.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.  I now see that if I use the nosort option to cleveref, I then get the exact output I needed (my post was a bit misleading about this).  Indeed, the reason why I wrote \label{problem:5,problem:4,problem:2} was that I wanted the output to be "problems 2.2, 2.1 and 1.3." I wonder why cleveref doesn't work this way by default?